# Magnetic energy in coil at time $t$ after circuit being hooked up

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance

> "A coil with inductance L = 50 mH and R = 600 ohm is coupled in series with a resistance R = 200 ohm to a battery with the voltage 12 V. How great is the magnetic energy in the coil at the time t = 10e-4 s after the closing of the circuit?"

I really do not understand this question at all. Magnetic energy at a certain time? I have no clue, please help.

Comment: This question is better suited for the Physics SE

Comment: An understanding of this problem is outside the scope of mathematics.  It requires the concepts of physics (and specifically electrical circuits).

Comment: Find the current $I$ as a function of time, then $E_{mag} = \frac 12 LI^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by the use of [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) we can write:

$$-12+\text{R}\cdot\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=-\text{L}\cdot\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}'\left(t\right)\tag1$$

Solving for $\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)$, gives:

$$\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=12\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-\frac{\text{R}}{\text{L}}\cdot t\right)}{\text{R}}\tag2$$

Now, for the energy in the coil:

$$\text{E}_{\space\text{L}}\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\text{P}_{\space\text{L}}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\int_0^t\text{U}_{\space\text{L}}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{I}_{\space\text{L}}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=$$
$$\text{L}\cdot\int_0^t\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\text{L}\cdot\frac{\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}^2\left(t\right)}{2}=\text{L}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(12\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-\frac{\text{R}}{\text{L}}\cdot t\right)}{\text{R}}\right)^2\tag3$$

Using the given values:

$$\text{E}_{\space\text{L}}\left(10^{-4}\right)=50\cdot10^{-3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(12\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-\frac{600+200}{50\cdot10^{-3}}\cdot10^{-4}\right)}{600+200}\right)^2\approx3.58295\cdot10^{-6}\tag4$$

---

> I set all the initial conditions equal to $0$.

Comment: You introduce a number of "unknowns" with no definitions, which is bound to leave Readers confused about your application of Faraday's Laws.  For example, the coil and the series resistor both have resistance values.  What does $R$ refer to in this context?

Comment: @hardmath I'm sorry. $\text{R}$ is the sum of the series resistors.

Comment: @hardmath Btw every electrical engineer should now these facts!

Answer (score 0):

The energy in the magnetic field is the integral of the square of the field over all space times a constant that depends on your units.  By conservation of energy it is the same as the energy absorbed by the coil because of the back emf.  You are expected to write a differential equation for current in the coil, solve it, and compute the energy in the field as a function of time.